# Timestamp in rhtml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, rhtml

I'm trying to show `timestamp` on `.rhtml` page, but it returns something like this:

```
Mon Dec 09 21:03:22 +0400 2013
```

How it should be:

```
2013.12.09 21:03:22
```

What's wrong?
This is how I do:

```
<%= message.time %>
```

Comment: Are you still on Ruby 1.8.7??

Comment: `Time.now.time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %T")` => `"2013.12.09 22:07:42"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

```
message.time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: `<%= message.time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%s")%>` not working

Comment: What do you mean not working? It would help if you post what you see . Try with `S` instead of `s` for second `<%= message.time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")%>`

Comment: @Vimsha `%S - Second of the minute (00..60)` and `%s - Number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.`

Comment: @Monk_Code: I know that. But for what user3083781 wants, it should be %S. Thank you for the explanation.